# Missing relationships after attaching a database by SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, relationship

Relationships between entities does not seem to exist after I imported a `.mdf` file by SQL Server Management Studio and I am sure that this database had many relationships between tables.

Does anyone have any idea on what might have happened and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you transferring this from a different server or just re-attching it?

Comment: From a differente server.

Comment: What do you mean by *import a .mdf file* - did you **attach** it to your SQL Server? Or what exactly did you do??

Comment: I attached it to the SQL Server expecting it to show table relationships, but it did not.

Comment: Are you referring to database diagram? Can you view what you are referring to on the original server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export a SQL Server 2008 Database Diagram to another DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019560/how-to-export-a-sql-server-2008-database-diagram-to-another-db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this post if you are referring to the database diagrams.  Database diagrams dot not come across with the mdf.

[How to export a SQL Server 2008 Database Diagram to another DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019560/how-to-export-a-sql-server-2008-database-diagram-to-another-db)