# Error Creating Database Diagram in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

When I attempt to create a database diagram, I get the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'diagram_id', table 'MyDB.dbo.sysdiagrams'; column does 
not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
The 'sp_creatediagram' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of
0 will be returned instead. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

I am using SSMS 2012.

The database is set at a compatibility level of SQL Server 2012 (110)

@@Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/128769/1186

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the diagram_ID when the table was created probably looked something like this

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name>
( diagram_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  n...,
)
```

This basically means that a NULL value cannot be inserted into that column because of the NOT NULL condition. So an insert statement like:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>
(Diagram_ID, n...,)
VALUES
(NULL, n...,)
```

Would fail because of the NULL you would need to have a value in there like (since I called it an integer):

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>
(Diagram_ID, n...,)
VALUES
(23, n...,)
```

The column may also be an indentity column in which case you have no controll over what can be inserted into the table.

Answer (score 2):

Go to system tables and look for systemdiagrams table, and turn to YES the "indentity Specification" property for the field diagram_id

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, this script solved my issues

```
DROP TABLE dbo.sysdiagrams;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams]
(
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [principal_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [diagram_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [version] [int] NULL,
    [definition] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UK_principal_name] UNIQUE ([principal_id],[name])
);

GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
  @name=N'microsoft_database_tools_support', 
  @value=1 , 
  @level0type=N'SCHEMA',
  @level0name=N'dbo', 
  @level1type=N'TABLE',
  @level1name=N'sysdiagrams';
GO
```

Comment: This does work but if you want to keep any existing diagrams then best to rename the [dbo].[sysdiagrams] table rather than drop it.   

So, steps would be:
1. rename [dbo].[sysdiagrams] to [dbo].[sysdiagramsSaved]
2. run the create table in this answer
3. run the exec sys.sp_add..... in this answer
4. resurrect your existing diagrams using inserts from sysdiagramsSaved to sysdiagrams. see [example insert statement in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415441/2041511).
5. when finished your resurrections, drop table sysdiagramsSaved

lemon squeezie

Answer (score 0):

[@Monzur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611747/2041511) does work - but if you want to keep any existing diagrams then best to rename the [dbo].[sysdiagrams] table rather than drop it.

So, steps would be:

1. rename [dbo].[sysdiagrams] to [dbo].[sysdiagramsSaved]
2. run the create table in this answer
3. run the exec sys.sp_add..... in this answer
4. resurrect your existing diagrams using inserts from sysdiagramsSaved to sysdiagrams. see [example insert statement in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415441/2041511).
5. when finished your resurrections, drop table sysdiagramsSaved

lemon squeezie